# Store argv to an int array

Tags: c, arrays, argv, calloc, argc

I have code like this to store `argv` to a dynamically allocated `int` array:

```
int *data;    // pointer to array of integer numbers
int size;     // size of data array

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // initialize array data
  size=argc;
  printf("%dSize=\n",size);
  printf("%d\n",argc);
  data=(int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
  int i=0;
  for (i=1;i<size;i++)
  {
   data[i]=argv[i];
   printf("%d\n",data[i]);
  }
  for (i=1;i<argc;i++)
  {
   printf("%d\n",argv[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run in command line:
`./sumprime 5 1 2 3 4`
It prints:

```
6Size=
6
15311660
15311662
15311664
15311666
15311668
15311660
15311662
15311664
15311666
15311668
```

Not an array of `5 1 2 3 4` as I expected. How can I store an `int` array from `argv` and then print it out?

Comment: These are pointer values of the arguments as char arrays. You should convert the argument strings to integers with `strtol` or `atoi` before storing them in your `int` array.

Comment: @MOehm : That's an answer not a comment; you should post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Should be:**

```
   data[i]=atoi(argv[i]);
```

Remember command line argument are strings. So even though you pass an integer in the command line its a string that needs to be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is an array of pointers to strings; the arguments are not integers, they are null terminated strings containing ASCII characters; you if you want to interpret them as integer values you will need to perform a conversion:

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    int size = argc - 1 ;
    int* data  = (int*)calloc( size, sizeof(int) ) ;

    printf( "Size = %d\n", size ) ;

    // For each argument...
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // convert string to an integer
        sscanf( argv[i + 1], "%d", &data[i] ) ;

       // Output the argument string and its converted value
        printf( "\"%s\" -> %d\n", argv[i + 1], data[i] ) ; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which for your input, outputs:

```
Size = 5
"5" -> 5
"1" -> 1
"2" -> 2
"3" -> 3
"4" -> 4
```

It is perhaps instructive to see what happens when you invoke:

```
./sumprime 5 1 hello 3 4
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Size = 5
"5" -> 5
"1" -> 1
"hello" -> 0
"3" -> 3
"4" -> 4
```